# preg_match accented characters

Tags: php, regex, encoding

I have an issue using preg_match with php.

I want my users to fill the *Name* field with only valid characters.
Ex: no numbers or special chars.

My site will eventually be bilingual but most of my visitors are french Canadians

I prefer utf-8 for my encoding.
So at the top of my document i have this tag :

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

I need to accept accented characters in my form and i have tryed this :

```
(preg_match('/^\p{L}+$/ui',$string))
```

But i cant get accent to be accepted this way.

Here is an example of what a name could contain as characters

> *jean-françois d'abiguäel*

That's pretty much as bad as it could get

Everyone seems to get `(preg_match('/^\p{L}+$/ui',$string))` working, but me.

I would need something like this :

```
/^\p{L}(\p{L}+[- ']?)*\p{L}$/ui
```

But i need to get it working.

My servers are IIS (godaddy)
PHP Version is 5.4
default timezone is set to America/Montreal

Thank you!

Comment: thats a real name, why break it?

Comment: Add `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');`.

Comment: depends on how the accented chars are embedded in the doc. e.g. `à`, which could be either `U+0061 + U+0300` (base letter `a` with accent), or as `U+00E0` (accented a). `\p{L}` matches "letters", which is what 0061 and 00E0 are classified as, while 00E0 is "mark" and not matched to \p{L}. Since your regex only allows "letters", if your string is letters+marks, the marks cause the entire string to not match.

Comment: @ZeroG: Try `if(preg_match('~^\p{L}+(?:[-\h']\p{L}+)*$~u',$string) == true)` or even `if(preg_match('~^\p{L}+(?:[-\h']\p{L}+)*$~u',$string, $matches) == true)`. Also please try my `ini_set` setting.

Comment: I am voting to close the question since OP was *inverting my condition in my IF statement. Was displaying bad request when it was actually good*.

Comment: Yeah that is to much for now i'm going back to watching Lost lol

Comment: @ZeroG: Be careful, don't lost yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This pattern should work:

```
/^\pL+(?>[- ']\pL+)*$/u
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQ9aY3/1)

But feel free to adapt it for more exotic names (For example names with a trailing quote or an apostrophe).

Comment: It is mine, too, you posted it earlier. I came up with `^\p{L}+(?:[-\h']\p{L}+)*$` a second or two later.

Comment: It matches `Père Noël` as well, it simply **must** be correct ;-)

Comment: if((preg_match("/^\pL+(?>[- ']\pL+)*$/u",$string)) == true) 
This wont accept nothing actualy. Maybe im calling it wrong

Comment: It won't match `Charles de Batz-Castelmore d’Artagnan`

Comment: @Jan: because you use an apostrophe (not a single quote).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I know why, but Wikipedia uses it as well. Just to make up an exotic example.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: My (flawed) answer has been accepted in error (in my opinion), so to compensate +1 for your better one.

Comment: @Jan: It doesn't matter, in this way you will win the sportsmanship badge. It's a very complicated question since there are many "exotic" names with unexpected characters. So the patterns posted here are only prototypes that needs to be improved.

Answer (score 2):

```
~^([\p{L}-\s']+)$~ui
```

Matches the following names:

1. Jean-François d'Abiguäel
2. François Hollande
3. Père Noël

See a demo on [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/pV6sG7/1).

Comment: This regex allows whitespace on both ends. Actually, it allows `--- -  ---`

Comment: @stribizhev: I would go with you, my answer has serious flaws and I'd vote for Casimir's.

Comment: lol thank you for taking the weight off my shoulder i felt bad for a moment. The worst is that both work and i was inverting my condition in my IF statement. Was displaying bad request when it was actually good.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can shorten @Casimir et Hippolyte's answer like so:

```
/^\pL+([- ']\pL+)*$/u
```